# how to revise field_to_native in Django/Rest FrameWork

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Recently, I am moved a django app from Django 1.4 to Django 1.11. I met a problem about field_to_native. I appreciate very much for any hints.

The original code:

```
class LoopgroupDqHyperlinkedIdentityField(relations.HyperlinkedIdentityField):
    def field_to_native(self, obj, field_name):
        # copied from superclass
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        format = self.format or self.context.get('format', None)
        view_name = self.view_name or self.parent.opts.view_name
        # new
        lgdq_attrs = 'loopgroup_id', 'year', 'month'
        view_kwargs = dict((X, getattr(obj, X)) for X in lgdq_attrs)
        return RF_reverse(view_name,
                kwargs=view_kwargs, request=request, format=format)

class LoopgroupDqSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = LoopgroupDqHyperlinkedIdentityField()

    class Meta:
        model = LoopgroupDq
        fields = tuple(X.name for X in LoopgroupDq._meta.fields) + ('url',)
```

The system returns the following error
  File "/srv/projects/python/dotfreewaydata/dataquality/serializers.py", line 43, in LoopgroupDqSerializer
    url = LoopgroupDqHyperlinkedIdentityField()
  File "/srv/virtual_environments/dotfreewaydata/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 408, in **init**
    assert view_name is not None, 'The `view_name` argument is required.'
AssertionError: The `view_name` argument is required.

I google this error message and found that field_to_native has been deprecated in Django Rest Framework 3.0.

In http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/
They mentioned

1)The field_from_native() and field_to_native() methods are removed.

2)Now if you need to access the entire object you'll instead need to override one or both of the following:

Use get_attribute to modify the attribute value passed to to_representation().
Use get_value to modify the data value passed to_internal_value().

The website gives some simple example. However, I don't understand.

Could anyone tell me how to modify "field_to_native" to "get_attribute" and "get_value" and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problems myself.

Yes. 'to_representation' is used to replace 'field_to_native'

```
class LoopgroupDqHyperlinkedIdentityField(relations.HyperlinkedIdentityField):
#    def field_to_native(self, obj, field_name):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        # copied from superclass
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        format = self.format or self.context.get('format', None)
        view_name = self.view_name or self.parent.opts.view_name
        # new
        lgdq_attrs = 'loopgroup_id', 'year', 'month'
        view_kwargs = dict((X, getattr(obj, X)) for X in lgdq_attrs)
        return RF_reverse(view_name,
                kwargs=view_kwargs, request=request, format=format)

class LoopgroupDqSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
#    url = LoopgroupDqHyperlinkedIdentityField()
    url = LoopgroupDqHyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="loopgroupdq-detail")
```

replace 'field_to_native' by 'to_representation'

view_name is required by HyperlinkedIdentityField
therefore, I provide
view_name="loopgroupdq-detail"

loopgroupdq-detail is defined in urls.py of the same app

url(r'^(?P\d+)/(?P\d+)/(?P\d{1,2})/$',
        LoopgroupDqDetail.as_view(), name='loopgroupdq-detail')